# allow space between two word using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to block special character except comma. So I am using code given below. Its is working but it is also removing space between two words. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QjVGV/58/)

```
var chars =/[(,\/\w)]/i;
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
  var value = this.value;
  var char = value[value.length-1];
    if(char !== ' ' || value.length==1 || (value[value.length-2]!==' ' )){

  if (!chars.test(char)) {
      $(this).val(value.substring(0, value.length-1));
  }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't you just include the space in your character class? i.e., `[ (,\/\w)]/i` (It now starts with a space).

Comment: @PA. Adding the space does "work", since his code removes the last character of the input when it does not match his regexp. Although he also allows `(`, `)`, and `/`. Not sure if that's part of the plan. And if you type fast enough characters will not be removed anyway :)

Comment: And no reason to use the `i` modifier here either =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of usability, manipulating the user's input as they're typing can be very frustrating. In addition, if the user types fast enough it doesn't work anyway (as mentioned by [Daniel Knippers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2858155/daniel-knippers), above)

A better bet would be to validate the user's input and let them know in real-time if the input is invalid.

Try this code:

```
var regex =/^[\w\s\,]*$/i;
$('input').keyup(function(e) {

    var message = regex.test(this.value) ? "" : "Error";
    $('#message').html(message);
});
```

[jsFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/QjVGV/67/)

Answer (score 0):

as far as i am understood, you wants that space should be allowed in txt box 
so,

here is your  [`ANSWER`](http://jsfiddle.net/QjVGV/60/)

you need to add space after `\w`

```
var chars =/[(,\/\w )]/i;
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
  var value = this.value;
  var char = value[value.length-1];
    if(char !== ' ' || value.length==1 || (value[value.length-2]!==' ' )){

  if (!chars.test(char)) {
      $(this).val(value.substring(0, value.length-1));
  }
    }
});
```

please note that i have added space after `\w`, so the regexp is `var chars =/[(,\/\w )]/i;`

Comment: @anni I don't know how typing in ALL CAPS relates to vocabulary?